# Anyone get the ID 2040:026d Hauppauge to work with Ubuntu 16.04 xenial. If so how?

Tags: 16.04, tv-tuner

I have been trying to get my Hauppauge WinTv-Dual HD usb tuner to work and have tried the different instructions on the web for them to fail.

Has anyone gotten this to work yet and if so can you provide info on how to do it.

Also how do I test it to verify it is working.